Sign in With Apple: ASAuthorizationController doesn’t show Authorisation Window from QT app
I’m trying to use Sign in With Apple  with a QT app.
We did use ASWebAuthenticationSession to be able to use OAuth in AuthenticationServices  for Non-Apple logins, like Google.
But now I’m trying to do the same for Sign in With Apple with their standard ASAuthorizationController, but from an QT/C++ app.
But the Autorisation-Controleler doesn’t show the Sign in With Apple WIndow
So I did set up an Interface with
@interface CWAppleAuthenticationServiceImpl : NSObject <ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding,ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate>
- (id)initWithOwner:(MyAppleAuthenticationService *) owner;

in MyAppleAuthenticationService.mm, mixing ObjC and Qt/C++
And a constructor
MyAppleAuthenticationService::MyAppleAuthenticationService()
{
        myImpl = [[MYAppleAuthenticationServiceImpl alloc] initWithOwner:this];
}

and an initWithOwner (which may be superflouous, I think we used the owner in the WebSession, but not here)
- (id)initWithOwner:(MyAppleAuthenticationService *)owner
{
    self = [super init];
    myOwner = owner; //MyAppleAuthenticationService *)

    // Setting up  Sign in with Apple Request with 
    // for e-mail and name 
    
    ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider *appleIDProvider = 
            [ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider new];
    ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest *request = 
        appleIDProvider.createRequest;
    request.requestedScopes = 
        @[ASAuthorizationScopeFullName, ASAuthorizationScopeEmail];

        ASAuthorizationController *controller = [[ASAuthorizationController alloc] initWithAuthorizationRequests:@[request]];

        controller.presentationContextProvider = self;
        controller.delegate = self;

        [controller performRequests];
        return self;
}

Now, I also implemented
- (ASPresentationAnchor)presentationAnchorForAuthorizationController:(ASAuthorizationController *)controller  API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15));

- (void)authorizationController:(ASAuthorizationController *)controller didCompleteWithAuthorization:(ASAuthorization *)authorization  API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15));
- (void)authorizationController:(ASAuthorizationController *)controller didCompleteWithError:(ASAuthorization *)authorization  API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15));

And when I call     [controller performRequests] presentationAnchorForAuthorizationController gets called.
Which basically creates a NSWindow, the same way we did for the Web-Authentication, only there with with presentationAnchorForWebAuthenticationSession
The good news – I guess – is that didCompleteWithError also gets called, afterwards, so I assume that the pane doesn’t get shown. But why?
Console says:
appname  User is member of local group
appname  User belongs to local, checking passcode
appname Authorization controller performAuthorizationWithContext called

So something is happening. But now I’m stumped.
Only idea I have left is that this only works when the app is signed with the proper entitlements
<dict>
<key>com.apple.developer.applesignin</key>
<array><string>Default</string></array>
</dict>

Which would be a bummer, since we can’t sign the app right now, for unrelated reasons.
